What's the ActiveMQ Artemis CLI command to get the timestamp of a message?
I am running this command:
./artemis queue browse --queue <queuename> --user admin --password password --url tcp://hostip:61616.

However, I am getting this error:
Unmatched arguments from index 1: 'browse'

If am running any command browse it does not work. I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.31.2. Could you please tell me the CLI command to get timestamp of queue message?

The reason you're getting an error is because you're attempting to use a command that doesn't exist. Try something like this instead:
./artemis browser --destination queue://<queuename> --user admin --password password --url tcp://hostip:61616

That said, the browser won't print out the timestamp of the message.
To be clear, there is no CLI command which returns the timestamp of the message. You'd need to write your own browser application for that.

This command was creating the "Adress and Queue" but not print the timestamp.  If am using browse and consumer command it wasn't work, so could please give the command.

I updated my answer to address your comment.

sorry it's not working actually it creates queue but i want to show the timestamp..

I highlighted the relevant portion in bold to make it more clear.
